# Renormalization conditions and proper vertices at tree level

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory, correlation-functions, 1pi-effective-action

I'm trying to understand a statement of my teacher of TQFT: he said that when expanding the effective action in terms of proper vertices, we can choose a new theory with only tree diagrams in order to eliminate divergences since the diagrams of $\Gamma$ are the same of the original action as a property of Legendre transformation. Then, in order to find those proper vertices he presented an alternative way to renormalize the theory  (that he said comes from Bogoliubov but I didn't find it) in which we don't need to introduce renormalization constants but we just impose renormalization conditions. I don't understand this procedure: do the renormalization conditions fix the proper vertices at tree level? And if so, why? Could you explain this procedure better to me?